# How to add a script in an octopress post?

Tags: blogs, octopress

Octopress posts contain markdown markup.

I want to add a widget which requires to put a `<script src="http://some-widget.com">` in the post.

The problem is that markdown turns it into a code block and it doesn't get executed.

I know that i can edit the .html output directly but the next time that i will do rake generate my edit will be lost.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried surrounding the code with a `<div>` tag? It's worked for me on several markdown/html issues.